# Check if a MySQL query has boolean values and display ✓ or ✖

Tags: php, html-table

I am new to mySQL and I am fetching several data from a DB and throwing it over a table like this:

```
// Create connection
$connection = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

//test if connection failed
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
  die( "Error: "
    . mysqli_connect_error()
    . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
    . ")" );
}

//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM SentEmails" );
$all_property = array(); //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
echo '<table class="data-table">
        <tr class="data-heading">'; //initialize table tag
while ( $property = mysqli_fetch_field( $result ) ) {
  echo '<td>' . $property->name . '/td>'; //get field name for header
  array_push( $all_property, $property->name ); //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag
    
    
//showing all data
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ( $all_property as $item ) {
    echo '<td>' . $row[ $item ] . '</td>'; //get items using property value
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

However some of the columns are boolean. I would like to display a "✓" or a "✖" in the appropriate column, instead of "1" or "0". Is this possible, without breaking down the SELECT or mounting the table over several steps? Perhaps a javascript function after the table is ready? Thank you.

Comment: This is a presentation question, therefore shoukd be handled in the php/html code, not in sql.

Comment: @Shadow I am not sure if I follow, I am using PHP to ask for SQL data and dumping it into an HTML table.

Comment: mysql is a database, it store and display whatever you put it there. You have to check the value you get from mysql using PHP and change the way it display i.e: ```if (true) { display tick } else {display cross }```

Comment: @catcon that's precisely what I want.